# Python If/Else Completing If function but not Else

Tags: python, python-2.7

Having some trouble with an `if/else` command in which only part of it is working.  When the script is run it will complete the `if` portion if the `name == check_file`, but if it is false it just skips the `else` statement and moves to the next task.  Here is the portion of the code that isn't functioning properly:

```
    for name in zip_file_names:
        copy_to = copy_this.get(name)
        if copy_to is not None:
            source_file = os.path.join(r'\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily' % item, name)
            destination = os.path.join(r"C:\%s" % item, copy_to)
            shutil.copy(source_file, destination)
            print name, "has been verified and copied."
        elif copy_to is not None:
            print "%s has been completed." % item
        else:
            print "Repoll %s for %s" % (item, business_date_one)
            print "Once information is downloaded press any key."
            re_download = raw_input(" ")
            ext_ver_cop_one()
```

The final `else` is for the file names that are unzipped that are not needed for the operation so I have to pass them, but I don't understand why the `if/else` inside of that `if/else` statement isn't functioning properly.  Especially because the `if` portion is working fine.  Thoughts?

Comment: Why do you check `name == sz_check_file` twice?

Comment: There are other files that I don't use that unpack from the same zip file and if I don't check it again it always fails to the else.

Comment: Why don't you describe exactly what is your task? It would be easier for us to figure out what you are trying to do.

Comment: I unpack a zip file, grab 4 specific files that are dated and then rename them to save in a new folder.  I've edited the above post to include more code so you can see why I originally have the extra if statement.

Comment: Are you requiring all four of the files you're looking for to be in the zip, or at least one of them? If the zip contains the "sz" file but not the "sc" file, should it be re-downloaded?

Comment: Yes it would need to be re-downloaded.  That's why I'm testing each file name against the names generated from the zip file.

Comment: Correction: It will ALWAYS contain both files.  The date that is in the file name, ie sz081413.prn, is the only thing that ever changes.  I'm trying to simply verify that date as what is expected so that I know the data in the file is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first `if` is evaluating to true (i.e., to reach the inner `if` at all), then the second one automatically will also evaluate to true, since it's the exact same condition.

You'll want to remove the outer `if`, as an `else: pass` at the end of a loop doesn't do anything. The iteration would just finish executing, anyway (unless there's more to the loop after this code block).

After further discussion, it sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
for name in zip_file_names:
    if name == sz_check_file:
        print name, "Date is verified."
        source_file = os.path.join(r'\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily' % item, sz_check_file)
        destination = os.path.join(r"C:\%s" % item, 'sales.xls')
        shutil.copy(source_file, destination)
        shutil.copy(source_file, r"C:\%s" % item)
        sz_found = true #Flag that sz was found
        print "sales.xls has been copied."
    elif name == sc_check_file:
        print name, "Date is verified."
        source_file = os.path.join(r'\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily' % item, sc_check_file)
        destination = os.path.join(r"C:\%s" % item, 'cosales.xls')
        shutil.copy(source_file, destination)
        shutil.copy(source_file, r"C:\%s" % item)
        sc_found = true #Flag that sc was found
        print "cosales.xls has been copied."
#Check flags to ensure all files found
if !(sz_found&&sc_found):
    print "Repoll %s for %s" % (item, business_date_seven)
    print "Once information is downloaded press any key."
    re_download = raw_input(" ")
    ext_ver_cop_seven()
```

I added flags for your different files - you said 4, so you'll need to extend the idea to check the others. You might also find another method of setting flags that's more extensible if you add files to copy, but that's the general idea. Keep track in the loop of what you've found, and check after the loop whether you found everything you need.

Comment: Right.  Remove the outer `if` statement, it does nothing for your code.

Comment: Okay, that makes total sense.  How then do I check just that file versus the other 12 in the zip file without an additional `if`? Will it need another variable, even if that variable is in fact exactly the same?

Comment: I've edited the original post so as to show you why I have the extra if originally.  Trying to run through file names and pull only the ones I want out of an extracted zip file.

Comment: @Ben For the names you don't want to pull, do you just want to do nothing? It looks like your inner `else`s are trying to re-download the zip - do you want to do that if none of the files you're looking for are found, or if not all of them are there, maybe?

Comment: Sure Michelle.  I currently have a folder with a zip file in it that has somewhere between 10 and 12 files zipped into it.  They are all named something like "sz0814213.prn" but I only need 4 of these files.  I have to grab these 4 files, the sz_check_file is a construction of the correct date plus both the prefix and suffix, rename them and then save them to a new location.  If the file isn't there or the name doesn't match, ie the date in the file name is wrong, I bring up the message to download it again and then once that's done pressing return will restart the process.

Comment: @Benjooster Right now it looks like you're trying to re-download every time you hit a file you don't want. You know there are going to be files you don't want, so this doesn't quite make sense. I'd keep a flag to track whether you've found your files.

Comment: @Michelle That's why I have the two identical if statements.  Without the second identical if statement that is exactly what happens.

Comment: @Ben Added some example code. You may want to tweak it a bit, but that should be the general structure.

Comment: Hi Michelle, I still can't get this to work and am getting syntax errors, name errors, or reference errors on them.  Can you explain how the flags should be working here?

Comment: You'll want to declare a flag for each file you want as false before you start looping through files (I think this is probably most of the problem), set the appropriate flag to true when you find a file you want, and check all of your flags after the loop. If they're all true, you're good to go; if one or more is false, you're missing a file and need to re-download.

Answer (score 1):

You want to take one action for a set of files and a different action for the rest? Try one if that handles all of the cases.

(edit: change selection criteria)

```
copy_this = {sz_check_file:'sales.xls', sc_check_file:'cosales.xls'}

for name in zip_file_names:
    copy_to = copy_this.get(name)
    if copy_to is not None:
        print name, "Date is verified."
        source_file = os.path.join(r'\\svr-dc\ftp site\%s\daily' % item, name)
        destination = os.path.join(r"C:\%s" % item, copy_to)
        shutil.copy(source_file, destination)
        shutil.copy(source_file, r"C:\%s" % item)
        print name, "has been copied."
    else:
        print "Repoll %s for %s" % (item, business_date_seven)
        print "Once information is downloaded press any key."
        re_download = raw_input(" ")
        ext_ver_cop_seven()
```

Comment: I did have this thought but tried iterating over a list.  The issue with this is that the file has to be renamed to sales or cosales from an sz081413.prn format and this doesn't accomplish that.

Comment: I used those names because I didn't know what's in sz_check-file, etc... You could put those in the copy_this tuple instead. if the match is more complex (not sz081413.prn exactly, but something close) you can use fnmatch.fnmatch or regular expressions.

Comment: This is actually working well, but on line 7 of your code where you've inserted `copy_to` it was previously using that space to rename the file to sales.xls or cosales.xls.  How would that be accomplished using your example code?

Comment: That's what `copy_to = copy_this.get(name)` does. It looks 'name' up in the copy_this dict and assigns its value to copy_to. So, if name is sz_check_file, copy_to will be 'sales.xls'.

Comment: Okay, I didn't see them copied to their destination but they were there and that was just my oversight.  I've expanded the tuple to include the following: `copy_this = {
 aj_check_file:'money.xls', cc_check_file:'count.xls',
 sc_check_file:'cosales.xls', sz_check_file:'sales.xls'
 }` It is only iterating over two of them, is there something that limits that in the code you've posted that I'm missing?

Comment: No, it should work for all of them. Your cc_check_file and etc... must not be quite right. Try `print 'files to check', copy_this.keys()` right before the for loop and `print 'checking', name` in the loop to see if there are any differences in the file. If this is Windows, you may have an upper/lower case problem.

Comment: So it's checking files that aren't included in the dict and pausing on that.  There are about 12 files in the zip only 4 of which I'm using.  I need to know when those 4 aren't correct but effectively pass on the remaining.

Comment: Sorted it, added an `elif copy_to is None: Pass` and it just flies right through all those files.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this didn't actually work as I've tested it more with files what didn't have the correct date and it just passes them.  I need to know when these four files have the wrong date on them and I'm totally stuck.  The rest of the files don't matter at all.

Comment: If I understand your encoding scheme, that's a question of how you build sz_check_file, etc...

Comment: I'm using the datetime module to generate multiple dates that I can then call using `business_date_one` through seven.  I'm constructing my `sz_check_file` in the following way. `sz_check_file = 'SZ' + business_date_one + '.prn'`  This has worked before but as I've added layers to the script and made it more complicated I believe my amateurish implementation was exposed.

Answer (score 0):

The code is a lot simpler if you invert it so you look at it from the standpoint of files you want, not of all files.  It's also nicer to keep the file names out of the body of the functions so it's easy to expand the set later.

```
def parse_zipfile (zip_names, **required):
   '''
   found is a dictionary with all the name > filename pairs that are present
   missing is a list of the names that are not found in found
   '''
   found = dict( (item,required[item]) for item in required if item in zip_names)
   missing = [item for item in required if not item in found]
  return found, missing

required_files = {'sz_checkfile':'sales.xls', 'sc_checkfile':'cosales.xls'}

found, missing = parse_zipfile(zip_names, **required_files}
if missing:
    #print error message
else:
    for source, target in found.items():
        #copy source to target
```

It would be a good idea to have a separate func to generate the **required dictionary with date-appropriate file string as keys